# Does Antivirus software upload files they find to their servers?

Tags: antivirus

As the question suggests, do antivirus softwares running on a local machine upload files they find malicious to their own servers for further research and is there a privacy concern here?

Comment: It depends entirely on the software, and are you aware of the huge Kaspersky issue around this last year? https://www.apnews.com/c360a29de62245c4abdc65d83cd467d7/Kaspersky:-We-uploaded-US-documents-but-quickly-deleted-them

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the AV product. Some AV products only upload new binary hashes, others the complete binary. For some, this is a configurable option. Looking at the AV products threat intelligence feed or similar offering might reveal their strategy in this area.

Answer (score 0):

It is DNS query based. The AV software queries for the hash as a DNS query where the hash is the subdomain for the AV domain. E.g.

d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.antivirus.com

Based on the response, the AV decides whether is malware or not.

Comment: Which ones do this? It would be nice if you added some specificity to the claim (or a citation)